# Moving shared folders and user profile folders to a new server

Tags: windows-server-2003, windows-server-2008-r2, file-server

I need to retire a file server soon.

I was wondering if there is a correct way to transfer department shares and user profile folders to the new server in a way that retains all folder and subfolder permissions settings?

And secondly are there any 'best practices' to follow when doing this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want to use the [File Server Migration Toolkit](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=10268).

Comment: Thanks.  Looks like the perfect tool.. almost.  I was hoping to break this task up into departments, but this tool seems to only let you do the job fully per share.  Our depts are subfolders of one shared folder called 'groups' and this tool won't let me be more specific than 'groups' in my selections.   I may go ahead and use it anyway.

Comment: @MrVimes you could also use Robocopy if you want to do it that way. Seen [here](http://sysbadmin.wordpress.com/2012/09/09/how-to-migrate-your-2003-file-server-to-2008-r2/)

Comment: Thanks @Cole .  Sounds like I'll be better off using robocopy.  More control over the process,  and I like that you can apparently do a 'difference' operation to update the files.